# How to add elements in List containing object

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

```
public class Role
{
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
    public int RoleId { get; set; }

    public Role(int roleid, string roleName)
    {
        RoleName = roleName;
        RoleId = roleid;
    }
}

public class RoleManagement
{

    public List<Role> RoleList = new List<Role>();
    RoleList.Add(1, "Software Engineer");
}
```

I am trying to add some values to the list

I am facing a errors such as

1. Type Expected
2. Tuple must contain atleast two elements

How can  i add some elements into the list

Comment: C# is a language of types. What is the type of `RoleList`? What is the type of the parameter(s) to `RoleList.Add()`? What type(s) are you passing? How can you create an object of the correct type(s) to pass to `RoleList.Add()`?

Answer (score 5):

You need to construct the Role object first, you can not add constructor parameters directly to the list:

```
RoleList.Add(new Role(1, "Software Engineer"));
```

Edit:

`RoleList` is an object of type `List<Role>`, in other words it's a `List` of objects of type `Role`. The `Add` method requires a single parameter, which should have the type `Role` (or derived). When calling `RoleList.Add(1, "Software Engineer")` you pass two parameters - of type `int` and `string`, while the method `Add` only accepts one: `List<Role>.Add(Role item)`. In which case you should be getting compiler error `CS1501 No overload for method 'Add' takes 2 arguments`.

To construct a `Role` object you must use the new keyword and provide constructor parameters if required: `new Role(1, "Software Engineer")`.

Comment: Can you be little precise ?

Comment: I would do a google search on Tuple it's really straight forward what @Maku has posted as an Answer in my Opinion